# "App proxy" send request to my "shopify shop" instead of my application ? [Shopify]

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, proxy, shopify

Whenever I send a request to my server App proxy sends it to Shopify store for no reason.

> My Proxy URL: https://example.com/test/public/action

But I get this request returned from Ajax

> GET
>   https://apiahmadztest.myshopify.com/action?shop=apiahmadztest.myshopify.com&path_prefix=%2Fapps%2Ffilter&timestamp=155579128&signature=9ceb23e244545faf5ad65f36b1196e6cfba57c9088a7d7dde96978970d
>   404 (Not Found)

Why it didn't send it to the proxy URL I defined? Am I doing something wrong or its a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem and it consists from two parts

1-  there's a problem with laravel when using Shopify proxy it always return mixed content error

2- you can't use https,  you have to start the Proxy URL with http  or it will return page not found error

anyway all you have is to make a php file like index  and make it as your templet file to display something in Shopify.

Once I find a solution to laravel I will edit this post.

---

I found solution for laravel  it because of the trailing slash at the end so it redirect the request if the url not a folder to solve this issue

remove these two lines from .htaccess  in public folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the complete route. You can choose a prefix in the Shopify partner dashboard and also a sub path.

The prefixes could be:

- a
- tools
- community
- apps

So if for example you choose the tools prefix and "mysubpath" sub path, your route should be something like this:  https://apiahmadztest.myshopify.com/tools/mysubpath/action?...

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies).

Comment: prefix is apps, and sub_path is filter||    the  action word from Proxy URL I added in the question above, which mean  shopify redirect Proxy URL to url I haven't specified!. so it sends request to App proxy successfully but  the returned data from ajax is wrong!

Comment: You should set your response content type as application/json as well.

I saw your answer, you say that you can't use https but I use https for all my App Proxies and they work well.

Comment: I get an error each time I use https for proxies, and many have same issue, maybe its from my server.  actually my content is html  I'm trying to make review plugin for my site.   should I put application/json  for html content as well ??

Comment: You should use the content type that correspond to your data, it could be liquid, html or json. Related to the https protocol, Shopify does not show proxy apps with certificates that are not valid or not trusted, I think self signed certificates also don't work. I used ngrok with proxy apps and it didn't work but I'm now using forward and it works perfectly.